# Outlook Addin Events C#

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, outlook, outlook-addin

I am working with Outlook Addin I have a database which get updated by some other application and according to that I am addin appointments and calenders in outlook through exchange server webservice managed api. This process of adding and updating appointments in the ews managed api is through a service but i have created an addin. Because you has the flexibility of changing of changing the appointment date and time also and when ever he does that i need to updated the other application regarding the time and date changed in outlook and also update the changes in database table. The problem in which I have stuck is that the user want to drag and drop the appointment instead of going to the addin and clicking on the button.  So i have attached the itemchange event on the appointment items in all the calenders. But when ever my service is adding new appointment or updates that so I don't understand how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Outlook Events Logger Add-in](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2010/07/01/outlook-events-tool/).

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the Calendar folder (Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)), store the Items object (MAPIFolder.Items) in a class variable to make sure it does not get garbage collected. track the Items.ItemAdd/ItemChange events.

Adding event handlers to *all* items in a folder is a very bad idea, especially if you are using an online Exchange store.